# remove event handler in vb event management run time

Tags: vb.net

When I debug an application sometime I do a ctrl-Break and then step into to see where the code is going and sometime there is fired event who interfere with that (usually all the paint event). So I would like to know if it's possible to disable/remove event handler in the vb event sub itself **at run time** :

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    statement that I can add to disable that event manager
    ... 
    code I don't want to be executed temporarily
    ....
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it your code that you want to stop running or is it code in the base classes?

Comment: It's my code (but it would be great if the "disable statement" could work with some base class code...)

Comment: It sounds like Sam's solution is pretty good for you.

Comment: no, it's not good at all : the question is : is it possible to disable the event handler at run time ? "on the fly" ? (because I know how to remove the event at the design time once I know it but it's annoying to see a unwanted throwed event at run time and then each time having to go at design time to disable it...)

Comment: Yes, but the `OnPaintBackground` method is **not** an event handler. It's the method that raises the event `PaintBackground`. So which one are you asking about?

Comment: OnPaintBackground is not an an event handler ? with that parameter : (ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) ? are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain - `OnPaintBackground` is the method you call to raise the event. You pass the event args that you want to send out to the handlers.

Comment: well is it possible, at the run time, to prevent the sub OnPaintBackground to be "fired" (because it's called by "no one"..)

Comment: It's called by the `Control` class itself in the BCL, along with a bunch of derived classes. The best you can do is override this method in control you write and only call `base.OnPaintBackground(e);` in an if statement based on whether or not you're debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally compile code, depending on your build type. So for example, you could change the code if you are doing a debug build.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(....)

#if DEBUG then
    <do something>
#else 
    <do something else>
#end if

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: yes but the question is : is it possible to disable the event handler at run time ? "on the fly" ? (because I know ow to remove the event at the design time once I know it but it's annoying to see a unwanted throwed event at run time and then each time having to go at design time to disable it...)

Comment: You can disable the event at runtime using RemoveHandler, but it depends how the object is declared.  You havent specified.

Comment: in vb the event are often declared by simply adding the corresponding sub, in that case adding the Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground simply add the event handler.